# Saving data from the web into Core Data while updating UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am pulling data from the web using a HTTP GET method. I am then taking the JSON data from the web and saving it into CoreData. I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells` that is updated with a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

However when I go to save data the tableView will only update what is already on screen and when I go to scroll down, the tableView becomes white.

In the log there are some errors that I receive:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete and reload the same index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 43}) with userInfo (null)

Here is my code that the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` uses in the `didChangeObject` method:

```
switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
```

Any ideas of what I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about your: ?

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

You can just take mine, it should definitely work, I used it in a couple of projects.
Just make your tableViewController to subclass this one. 
and then initialize and pass your fetchedResultsController to your tableViewController and call there:

```
[self setupFetchedResultsController:yourFetchResultsController];
```

SMCoreDataTableViewController.m:

```
#import "SMCoreDataTableViewController.h"

@interface SMCoreDataTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL beganUpdates;
@end

@implementation SMCoreDataTableViewController

- (void)performFetch
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController) {
        if (self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching %@ with predicate: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName, self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate);
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching all %@ (i.e., no predicate)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName);
        }
        NSError *error;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    } else {
        if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] no NSFetchedResultsController (yet?)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController:(NSFetchedResultsController *)newfrc
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *oldfrc = _fetchedResultsController;
    if (newfrc != oldfrc) {
        _fetchedResultsController = newfrc;
        newfrc.delegate = self;
        if ((!self.title || [self.title isEqualToString:oldfrc.fetchRequest.entity.name]) && (!self.navigationController || !self.navigationItem.title)) {
            self.title = newfrc.fetchRequest.entity.name;
        }
        if (newfrc) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), oldfrc ? @"updated" : @"set");
            [self performFetch];
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] reset to nil", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
}

#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        self.beganUpdates = YES;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (self.beganUpdates) [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges
{
    _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = NO;
}

- (void)setSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext:(BOOL)suspend
{
    if (suspend) {
        _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges) withObject:0 afterDelay:0];
    }
}

@end
```

SMCoreDataTableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface SMCoreDataTableViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext;
@property BOOL debug;

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController:(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController;

@end
```